# Whats the difference between the Photon Sphere and the Marginally bound orbit?

Tags: black-holes, photons, orbital-motion

Whats the difference between the Photon Sphere and the Marginally bound orbit?
Why does photon sphere have a radius of 1.5Rs, while the Marginally bound orbit has a radius of 2Rs?

Comment: What’s the difference between a cow and a pear? (Could you elaborate on what confuses you between the concepts?)

Comment: I would like to understand what the marginally bound circular orbit is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the light ring (photon orbit) and the marginally bound circular orbit, are cases of unstable circular orbits. The light ring is a null orbit, i.e. the orbit followed by a massless particle (such as a photon). Any massive particle would need **infinite** energy to follow this orbit.

The marginally bound circular orbit on the other hand is defined as the unstable circular orbit whose energy is equal to the rest mass of the particle. This means that if the orbit is perturbed towards infinity, the particle would reach infinity with zero velocity. (A particle escaping the light ring on the other hand would reach infinity travelling at the speed of light.)

So, why is the radius of the light ring smaller than that of the marginally bound circular orbit? One way to see this is to note that the energy of unstable circular orbits increases as the radius of the orbit decreases. Since infinity is bigger than a finite energy, the marginally bound circular orbit must lie outside the light ring. (Alternatively we could have noted that the light ring is the smallest possible circular orbit.)

The actual values (2Rs and 1.5Rs) for these orbits are simply how these work out for a Schwarzschild black hole. If one were to add spin or charge to the black hole the radii of these orbits would change. However, it would still be true that the marginally bound circular orbit lies outside the light ring.

Comment: So does that mean a massey particle can have a circular orbit around a black hole bewteen the marginally bound circular orbit and the photon sphere?

Comment: @blademan9999 Yes (but as any circular orbit below the ISCO it would be unstable)

Comment: "*orbit whose energy is equal to the rest mass of the particle*" - The orbit radius doesn't depend on the particle mass simply because two particles can be on the same orbit and this is equivalent to one larger particle. Could you please clarify your statement?

Comment: @safesphere The energy of an orbit is the energy of a particle following that orbit. This energy obviously depends on the rest mass of the particle.  Nonetheless there is a unique circular orbit, where a particle following that orbit has energy equal to its rest mass.

Comment: If you want to be precise about it, there a unique specific energy associated to each orbit. The MBCO is the unstable circular orbit with specific energy 1.

Comment: If by "specific energy" you mean "the ratio of the particle energy to its rest mass", then it makes sense, but could you please clarify what type of energy is implied here (e.g. the kinetic energy or full, energy, etc.) and in which coordinates it is measured (e.g. Schwarzschild), and also how the rest mass is measured (e.g. in the Schwarzschild coordinates at infinity or at rest at the orbit location)? Thanks! +1

Comment: Energy here is the contraction of the particle’s 4- momentum with the timelike Killing vector of the Schwarzschild spacetime (normalized such that it has length -1 at infinity). The rest mass is given by the square root of minus the 4-momentum contracted with itself. Both are coordinate independent quantities. @safesphere

Answer (score 2):

For a circular orbit around a large mass of mass $M$ under Schwarzschild geometry the energy of the the body of mass $m$ in circular orbit may be written as:

$$E=mc^2\frac{1-2 \frac{GM}{rc^2}}{\sqrt{1-3\frac{GM}{rc^2}}}\tag{1} $$

assuming $E=mc^2$ for the same object at rest at infinity. From this expression we see that the energy to sustain a circular orbit becomes infinite at the photon radius of $r=3GM/c^2$. By taking the derivative of (1) with respect to $r$ we can also see that (1) has a minimum at $r=6GM/c^2$, the so called "innermost stable circular orbit".

There is another "special" radial distance known as the "marginally bound circular orbit". As stated in the other answer provided here "The marginally bound circular orbit on the other hand is defined as the unstable circular orbit whose energy is equal to the rest mass of the particle". Mathematically this can be written as:

$$E=mc^2\frac{1-2 \frac{GM}{rc^2}}{\sqrt{1-3\frac{GM}{rc^2}}}\tag{2}=mc^2 $$

or equivalently:

$1-2 \frac{GM}{rc^2}=\sqrt{1-3\frac{GM}{rc^2}}$

which holds true for $r=4GM/(c^2)$.

That is why the photon radius is at $r=\frac{3GM}{c^2}$ while the "marginally bound circular orbit" is located at $r=\frac{4GM}{c^2}$.